# How Can Scripts Exchange Data In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*for starters i have incredibly basic knowledge of c# and unity, so pardon my ignorance*

Anyway, When I make a game, I have everything controlled by a single script. I have found some limitations with said approach. So I now want to organize my project with multiple scripts. I understand scripts in the same namespace can access classes from other scripts but I don't know how they can exchange data (like Vector3 or String Values). I've tried looking stuff up online but I've never found the right answers.

Comment: Without having much to go on, you want to look into `manager`s. If you want multiple managers to interact with each other, one can have a property of another type, and you in the visual hierarchy and Inspector, you can drag the object with the child manager script into the main script object's property. Then within the main script manager, you can do something like `this.childManager.someFunction()` (please use better names). I'll see if I can find a good example and/or make one for you, if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: P.S. a `manager` is just a description of the script's purpose. It is really just a script on an empty game object that is meant to only have one instance and control things within the game.

Comment: You're asking a question that could take a book to answer. You should look for introductory material for object-oriented programming (OOP). I could go on about this, but again it's really a book's worth of material. Your first script *instance* (object) would hold references to other script *instances* (objects) and you communicate via public properties and methods.